# Restore entire databases at once in localhost

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Prior to the formatting of my PC, i backed up the entire database set through phpmyadmin.

Now when i am restoring my exported sql file, its showing me an error "#1046 No Database selected".

Going through many question answers, i got to know that i should have exported the databases one by one. But now the mistake has already happened, and i have no other alternative to backup the database again, i am left with the already backed up file of "Entire Databases of server".

How to recover them now?

Comment: from where ur restoring terminal or phpmyadmin????

Comment: currently i am trying from phpmyadmin

Comment: will it work from terminal???? if yes, then how?

Comment: before importing did you created respective DB's in phpmyadmin???

Comment: no, neither did i know the name of all DB's that i have exported

Comment: create  a database then import...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159726/discussion-between-yogesh-prajapati-and-kranthi).

Comment: did so, but what it did was, it exported all the tables of all the databases in a single database, where some table names overlapped and hence errors